# Merging equal parts in more than one file

Tags: r

I have 3 files:
File number 1 is (F1.txt):

```
"se" "su"
"1" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.227701005025126
"2" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.286903266331658
"3" "<{FB}>" 0.121309673366834
```

File number 2 is (F2.txt):

```
"se" "su"
"1" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.28881
"2" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.273897
"3" "<{FB}>" 0.19998
```

File number 3 is (F3.txt):

```
"se" "su"
"1" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.256758
"2" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.299991
"3" "<{FB423}>" 0.17890
```

I would like to create one long file that at the beginning of each row there will be an indication in what file the "su" field has occurred and a list of its the following occurrence:

The output file (OT.txt):

```
  "se" "su"
    <{FBB rr e2}> in files: 1, 2, 3 
    file1: "1" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.227701005025126
    file2: "1" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.28881
    file3: "2" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.299991
    <{FB EX PR}> in files 1,2,3:
    file1: "2" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.286903266331658
    file2: "2" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.273897
    file3: "1" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.256758
    <{FB}> in files: 1,2 
    file1: "3" "<{FB}>" 0.121309673366834
    file2: "3" "<{FB}>" 0.19998
    <{FB423}> in files: 3
    file3:"3" "<{FB423}>" 0.17890
```

Comment: Is there anything you've already tried?

Comment: I transformed each of them into dataframe by datx <- read.table(file.choose(), head=T, as.is=T). It is quite easy to do with SQL but I am not sure about R

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be R?

Comment: Yes I processed all my data there (very much effort) and the users use only R.

Comment: I think the idea here is to put them all into one data frame to add the source file number to each row and to sort it by su.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
#combining data
F1 <- read.table(text='"se" "su"
"1" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.227701005025126
"2" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.286903266331658
"3" "<{FB}>" 0.121309673366834', header=T)
F1$file <- 1
F2 <- read.table(text='"se" "su"
                 "1" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.28881
                 "2" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.273897
                 "3" "<{FB}>" 0.19998', header=T)

F2$file <- 2
F3 <- read.table(text='"se" "su"
"1" "<{FB EX PR}>" 0.256758
"2" "<{FBB rr e2}>" 0.299991
"3" "<{FB423}>" 0.17890'
)

F3$file <- 3


#make one big datafile

FF <- do.call(rbind,list(F1,F2,F3))
str(FF)

#sort

res <- FF[with(FF, order(se,su)),]
res

#or with writing to file- very hacky
outputfile <- "OT.txt"
lapply(split(FF,FF$se),function(x){
  current_name=unique(x$se)
  header = sprintf("%s in files %s\n",unique(x$se), paste(sort(x$file),collapse=", "))
  cat(header,file=outputfile,append=T)
  write.table(x[order(x$su),c("se","su")],file=outputfile,append=T,col.names=F)
}
)
```

Comment: Thanks! The only question how can we add the required headlines at the specific locations?

Comment: Thanks a lot works excellent! Except for cases in which there are {A; B} and {A} the function sort {A; B} in the same order as if it was {A}. However, in my case I wouldn't like to connect between {A; B} and {A} it is as if {A; B} is {C} something else. In addition, I have some problems to insert special characters to the read.table in cases such as {\N}

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean but I'm confident you can figure it out.